# integrate $\int \frac{x^4+4x+6}{(2-x)^2(4+x^2)}$

Tags: integration

> $$\int \frac{x^4+4x+6}{(2-x)^2(4+x^2)}$$

$(2-x)^2(4+x^2)=x^4-4x^3+8x^2-16x+16$

$$\int \frac{x^4+4x+6}{x^4-4x^3+8x^2-16x+16}$$

Is there is anything to do else than long division?

Comment: You need to do the long division and then find a partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @Nehorai what's wrong with long division?

Answer (score 4):

I know that you asked without long division, but

$$\int \frac{x^4+4x+6}{(x-2)^2(x^2+4)}\stackrel{\text{L.div}}{=}\frac 1 8 \int\frac{11x-8}{x^2+4}dx+\frac{21}{8}\int\frac{dx}{x-2}dx+\frac{15}{4}\int \frac{dx}{(x-2)^2}+\int1 dx=\dots$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{x^4+4x+6}{(2-x)^2(4+x^2)}$$
$$(2-x)^2(4+x^2)=x^4-4x^3+20x^2-16x+16=(x^4+4x+6)-(4x^3-20x^2-20x+22)$$
$$\int \frac{x^4+4x+6}{(2-x)^2(4+x^2)}=x-\int \frac{4x^3-20x^2-20x+22}{(2-x)^2(4+x^2)}$$
$$-4(2-x)(4+x^2)=4x^3-8x^2+16x-32=(4x^3-20x^2-20x+22)-(-12x^2-36x+54)$$
$$\int \frac{x^4+4x+6}{(2-x)^2(4+x^2)}=x-\int{\frac{1}{4(2-x)}}+\int \frac{-12x^2-36x+54}{4(2-x)^2(4+x^2)}$$
And so on...